# How to perform math operations within one column?

Tags: python

I have a text file with two rows, and I need to subtract the measure of row 2 from the measure of row 1 using Python.  I know I could do this manually, but my assignment requires it to be coded.  Ideally, I would print this value - I don't need to append it to the table.

```
ROW ID | Name | Measure
1 | Library | 3627
2 | Dorm | 725
```

Here is my code so far:

```
uDistFile = open("T:\\Students\\kheuser\\semprojclean\\udistance.txt","r")
uBusStops = uDistFile.readlines()[1:]

for stop in uBusStops:
    aList = stop.split(",")
    print "measures are", aList[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in what is known as a DSV (short for [Delimiter Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values)) format. Python has a module named `csv` that can read most flavors of them. (Its first letter is "`c`" because the traditionally the delimiter used was a comma.)

The code below uses it to do what you want (and will handle any number of rows):

```
import csv

filename = "udistance.txt"
column = "Measure"

with open(filename, newline="") as uDistFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(uDistFile, delimiter="|", skipinitialspace=True)
    values = [int(row[column]) for row in reader]

print('values:', values)
print('total:', sum(values))
```

Output:

```
values: [3627, 725]
total: 4352
```